# unable to update slicer value using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

The following is the code i am using to update the value of my slicer.

```
Sub country_select()

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

 country_selected = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).Name
 ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Country").ClearManualFilter

 For Count = 1 To 13 'countries
 country = Sheet5.Range("E2").Offset(Count, 0).Value
If country = country_selected Then
ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Country").SlicerItems(country).Selected = True
Else

ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Country").SlicerItems(country).Selected = 
 False
  End If
Next Count

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

The country variable is not updating its value(only taking *empty* value). 
I don't understand the reason for this.
I am trying to link a map to a macro hence the input.

Comment: You've asked quite a few questions recently, but haven't yet accepted any answers. How 'bout going back through the questions you've asked, and accepting those answers that best address your problem? See stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you need to interate through the range E3:E14. If all you want to do is to set the Slicer to show the item corresponding to the shape the user has selected, I would just use something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub country_select()

Dim si As SlicerItem
Dim Country As String

Dim sc As SlicerCache

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

 Country = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).Name
 Set sc = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Country")

 With sc
    .ClearAllFilters
    For Each si In sc.SlicerItems
        If si.Name <> Country Then si.Selected = False
    Next si
End With


Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Note that if the slicer was for a PivotTable (and not for a Table) I would set the .ManualUpdate propery of the PivotTable to TRUE before the loop, and to FALSE after, so that the PivotTable didn't try to update after each and every SlicerItem is selected.

And if this was for a PivotTable (and not for a Table) there is no need to iterate over a Slicer at all (which is inefficient/slow). Instead, just put the Country field in the Pivot as a PageField, and just set the .CurrentPage of the PageField directly, like so:

```
Sub FilterPivot()

Dim pf As PivotField

Set pf = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Country")
pf.CurrentPage = Application.Caller

End Sub
```